# Phonegap web service call only works with local json file (not localhost)

Tags: jquery, web-services, cordova

I want to call a restful web service which returns Json from my phoneGap application and I used the code below :

```
$(document).on("vclick","#get" , function(){
        $.getJSON( "http://192.168.1.9:52827/Service.svc/welcome/arman", function( data ) {

$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
$("#serv").append(val + "<br>");
});
});
});
```

and corresponding section in my index.html is :

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1 class="ui-btn-corner-br">Page Two</h1>

</div>
 <div data-role="content">
 <button id = "get"> send request </button>
<div  class = imageContainer>   
    <img src = 'images/2.jpg' draggable="false">
</div>

<div id = "serv">
</div>
```

I'm not going for a simulator or actual device yet, when I open it on a browser, nothing happens. but if I replace the url with the address of saved json file, it works fine.

I tested the web service, it works fine. And I also added

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

to my config.xml file.

Comment: can you check console if ajax call is successful?

Comment: how can I do it ? I'm a beginner at phonegap and I'm using dreamweaver for it. (and online build)

Comment: use browser developer tools or firebug addon of firefox

Comment: I did it and here's the error :Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.1.9:52827/Service.svc/welcome/arman. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: cross origin is not allowed on your server

Comment: so what should I do ?

Comment: google ajax call cross origin

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution . All I needed to do was adding

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

to the web.config file in my asp web service so that it allows access to external applications.